# Phonegap - Geolocation with PowerSaving and GPS Only Mode

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I have a problem with Geolocation on Phonegap build for Android

This is my function to get Position of device

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 150000 }); //2.5 mins timeout
```

I also use

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 150000 }); //2.5 mins timeout
```

But both of them only work if i set Mode of Location on Mobile is : High accuracy

The rest are : Power saving and GPS Only don't work.

Did i make some mistake or missing something ?

Thank you !!

Comment: That's because you set enable high accuracy as true  make this parameter false,may be this will work

Comment: I have tried to change it to false, but the same result happened :(